# using Dart snapshots - "Wrong script snapshot version"

Tags: dart

I have a very interesting issue I am running into, I'm running my Dart system fine locally from .dart files. But after my build process I'm producing .snapshot files, when ran I receive a "Wrong script snapshot version" error.

As suggested on various email lists, I tried rebuilding snapshots by running 'dart'.

I am currently using Dart 1.9.1.

Thank you.
 
ps. Dart rocks! :)

Comment: You are sure the Dart VM where you create the snapshot and where you execute the snapshot are exactly the same? Same version, same platform?
Maybe you could create the snapshot inside the Docker container as task in the dockerfile.

Comment: ok, so just for sanity reasons I redownloaded Dart 1.9.1, used it to build a new snapshot, then rebuilt the Docker image with that snapshot and the same Dart 1.9.1 sdk, and its again throwing the same error. As far as building the snapshot inside the container Id rather not, since I have a custom build system that does other processing before and after snapshot building, and my docker container is built via static Dockerfiles....

Comment: How does the command look like which invokes your Dart snapshot within Docker?

Comment: dart --checked main.snapshot

Comment: got my info from https://www.dartlang.org/articles/snapshots/

Comment: Ok, so this is officially not a Docker issue, just ran it from the command line locally on my host and still getting the same error... using the same dart binary to generate and attempt to run the snapshot

Comment: Can you provide a sample project which allows to reproduce the problem?
I just tried it with one of my scripts and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

very strange. I actually had leftover --enable_async flags (from the 1.8.5 SDK) in my Dart build functions, and as soon as I removed them the generate shapshots were valid.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you upgrade Dart but don't delete existing snapshots `/project-name/.pub/bin` created by a previous version of Dart automatically.

I'd try to delete the entire folder:

```
$ rm -rf .pub
```

and then regenerate snapshots by running Dart:

```
$ pub get
$ dart main.dart
```